# MUI: How to make one box a fixed height, and another box that takes up the rest of the width with scrollable content

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So the "height: 'calc(100% - 170px)'" trick works fine, but it's fine if I know the height of the header. How can I divide my viewbox this way if I don't know the H of the header.

It seems obvious that everyone needs this, but I can't find the answer.

```
  <Box sx={{ height: "98vh" }}>

            <Box sx={{ width: '100%', height: '170px', backgroundColor: '#aabbbb' }}
            >
                APPBAR
            </Box>
            <Box
                sx={{
                    width: '100%',
                    height: 'calc(100% - 170px)',
                    overflow: 'auto'
                }}
            >
                <Card sx={{ height: '2000px', backgroundColor: 'lightgreen' }}>
                    <CardContent>LIST</CardContent>
                </Card>
            </Box>
        </Box>
```

So I tried all the variations of flexboxes but they work well with fixed content. If I have flexible height it doesn't work as I expect. There should be something which tell to the box "give me the rest of the viewport height"

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally it seems to be I found solution:

```
 <Box sx={{ height: '98vh', display:'flex', flexDirection:'column' }}>

        <Box sx={{ 
            width: '100%',
             height: '100px',
             backgroundColor: '#aabbbb' }}
        >
            APPBAR
        </Box>
        <Box
            sx={{
                width: '100%',                   
                overflow: 'auto',
                flex:1
            }}
        >
            <Card sx={{ height: '2000px', backgroundColor: 'lightgreen' }}>
                <CardContent>LIST</CardContent>
            </Card>
        </Box>
    </Box>
```